# Gulp doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gulp, ubuntu-16.04

I have one problem. I can't run Gulp on Ubuntu 16.04. So,
I installed Nodejs:

```
dmitriy@dmitriy-K53SD:~$ nodejs -v
v7.0.0
```

Installed npm:

```
dmitriy@dmitriy-K53SD:~$ npm -v
3.10.8
```

Created a folder with my project. 
Initialized npm by command:

```
npm init
```

I have added gulp to the project: `npm i gulp --save-dev`

For now, my package.json file look like:

```
{
  "name": "Test task",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Front-end test fot Soft Industry",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Dmytro Kovbasa",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  }
}
```

Then, I have created file gulpfile.js And there have wrote simple task for example:

```
gulp.task('hello', function() {
  console.log('Hello world');
});
```

After, when I have tried run this task by command: `gulp hello`
I have been getting error:

```
dmitriy@dmitriy-K53SD:~/work/D.Kovbasa front-end test$ gulp hello
/home/dmitriy/work/D.Kovbasa front-end test/gulpfile.js:2
gulp.task('hello', function() {
^

ReferenceError: gulp is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dmitriy/work/D.Kovbasa front-end test/gulpfile.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:198:16)
```

Please, could you help me? where is the problem?

Comment: You need to `require()` gulp.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem